# update flask with new json data

Tags: flask

I'm new to flask and my goal is to have a ui web page that edits json data and the other page "/json" is supposed to update without me refreshing the page. I wonder if there is a simple solution to do this. This is my code so far.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/json")
def json():
    data = {
        "lights" : "on",
        "animation" : "stack_led",
    }

    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, you will need JavaScript fetch API.

You didn't specify what exactly you want to do with that data, so (by the fact that you want to render the template) I will assume that you want to display it.
First of all, don't name the endpoints with reserved names such as "json". We will make it as follows:

```py
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/lightbulbaction", methods=('GET',))
def lightbulb_action():

    return jsonify({
        "lights" : "on",
        "animation" : "stack_led",
    })
```

Now, in the body of your index.html add a clickable element and js script

```html
<span id="light-bulb" onclick="switchLight()">LIGHTBULB</span>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>
```

Flask by default looks for .css and .js files in /static folder, so create one in your project structure and add a file app.js into it with following code:

```js
function switchLight() {
    let bulb = document.getElementById('light-bulb');

    fetch('/lightbulbaction', { method: "GET" })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        bulb.innerHTML = data["lights"]
    })
    .catch((e) => alert("Power blackout"));
}
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├── static
│   ├── app.js
│── templates  
│   ├── index.html 
└── app.py
```